# Apply a Bridge pattern to an existing class design

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, refactoring, bridge

[image: No Bridge]


As you can see I have an interface for Debug Events and two operations Attach and Detach. On top of this I have to implement a Windows and Linux version so the current design does not scale at all.

Imagine that I have to add:

- DebugEventThread <- DebugEventThreadAttach <- DebugEventThreadDetach
- DebugEventProcess <- DebugEventProcessAttach <- DebugEventProcessDetach

This design blows out of proportions...

I know Bridge pattern would be a solution to this problem but how would it be applied in this case?

**Update:**
As a first fix I'm thinking of adding a member Operation (Attach/Detach) to DebugEventModule. This way no more subclass is needed for different type of attach/detach operations:


**1.**

[image: Bridge]

The bridge between DebugEventModule -> DebugEventModuleImpl seems useless to me at this point, can you see any benefit of having a bridge here? Without a bridge I would have:


**2.**

[image: Inheritance]

What about moving platform specific stuff (OS stuff) out of the way with a Bridge? Something like this:


**3.**

[image: Platform abstraction]

I'm thinking that in this last design the platform_specific() functions would be Module, Thread, Process specific and this goes against the "One Responsibility Principal", I wouldn't want this class to become a "mammoth", to become a combination of unrelated functions.

**Update 2:**
Current implementation for DebugEvent + DebugEventModule:

```
    class DebugEvent {
    public:
      DebugEvent(uint32_t processId,
                 uint32_t threadId);
      virtual ~DebugEvent();
      virtual void Process() = 0;
    private:
      uint32_t _processId;
      uint32_t _threadId;
    };

    class DebugEventModule : public DebugEvent {
    public:
      DebugEventModule (uint32_t processId,
                        uint32_t threadId,
                        handle_t fileHandle,
                        hmodule_t baseOfDll,
                        address_t imageName,
                        uint16_t isUnicode);
      virtual ~DebugEventModule();
      virtual void Process();
    private:
      handle_t _fileHandle;
      hmodule_t _baseOfDll;
      address_t _imageName;
      uint16_t _isUnicode;
    };

    class DebugEventModuleAttach : public DebugEventModule {};
    class DebugEventModuleDetach : public DebugEventModule {};

    class DebugEventModuleAttachWindows : public DebugEventModuleAttach {};
    class DebugEventModuleAttachLinux : public DebugEventModuleAttach {};

    class DebugEventModuleDetachWindows : public DebugEventModuleDetach {};
    class DebugEventModuleDetachLinux : public DebugEventModuleDetach {};
```

The idea is to make a platform independent version of Windows DEBUG_EVENT:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Windows DEBUG_EVENT looks like this:

```
    typedef struct _DEBUG_EVENT {
      DWORD dwDebugEventCode;
      DWORD dwProcessId;
      DWORD dwThreadId;
      union {
        EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO      Exception;
        CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO  CreateThread;
        CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO CreateProcessInfo;
        EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_INFO    ExitThread;
        EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO   ExitProcess;
        LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO       LoadDll; // - This was DebugEventModuleAttach in the original design
        UNLOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO     UnloadDll; // - This was DebugEventModuleDetach in the original design
        OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO  DebugString;
        RIP_INFO                  RipInfo;
      } u;
    } DEBUG_EVENT, *LPDEBUG_EVENT;
```

Comment: (1) Identify the methods that depend on the OS; (2) build a compatibility layer that provides the same services in a OS-agnostic way; (3) write your model about debug events using the compatibility layer, and (4) before using your model instantiate the implementation of the compatibility layer that corresponds to the current OS.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia: Thank you for the comment. Please see the updates I posted, in the above design I tried as much as possible to break down the problem in small pieces "Type of Debug Event" + Operation + OS. Can you help me with the right approach? I think solving this example would help others to solve a similar issue in the future.

Comment: It is not clear to me what a `DebugEvent` and a `DebugEventModule` are.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia: See Update 2 please. Added some code and a link to what I'm trying to abstract.

Comment: Approach 3 looks good to me. At this point I personally would start coding to test the initial ideas and uncover new ones. You already know you don't want the explosion of classes in your hierarchy, so that won't happen. Go ahead with the coding and refactor as you learn more.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia: In the end I used inheritance for attach and detach operations because DebugEventModuleAttach and DebugEventModuleDetach turned out to be quite different, and the member of the classes are also different. The interface on the other hand is the same so inheritance was ok in this case. The platform part of the problem will be solved with free form functions. This way the OS specific functions will not be part of the OOP hierarchy and can be reused. So now I have the original design (first UML diagram) without the OS specific classes. Thank you for your feedback.